# How can I access dom element which is present under the shadow root element in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, angular-material

```
<div>

<external-component>

#shadow-root

<div class="test">

<button value="submit"></button>

</div>

</external-component>

</div>
```

Want to access submit button. I have tried using ElementRef I am not able to access the element, because it's present under shadowDom. If any one can help me about this.

Comment: Why would you need the elementRef to the button element. You can add `(click)` to get the click event !!

Answer (score 6):

You can query like below:

```
constructor(ele: ElementRef){}

//Inside your function
const shadowRoot: DocumentFragment = this.ele.nativeElement.shadowRoot;
const Button = shadowRoot.querySelector('button');
```

Comment: This approach is not working. I am getting shadowRoot value as null. Please let me know in case you have any idea? I am trying to access the shadow DOM of HTML date input control.

Comment: @Himanshu Do you use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom,` in `@Component` annotation? If not, then there is no shadow dom at all.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, you need to update the button with a templateVariable

```
<button #buttonRef arr='value'></button>
```

Then, in the component, you can do a `ViewChild` to get the reference and access values.

```
@ViewChild('buttonRef', {static: true}) button: ElementRef<HTMLButtonElement>;
```

You should be able to access the button using `this.button` in your ts code.

Hope this helps